# Generating content from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, module

I am working on a jQuery tooltip module for personal use. In my code I'm using jQuery's mousemove and mouseout functions in order to generate the tooltip. However, when I move my mouse over the element it hits the if statement in the build function and says that the tooltip should be there even though I can see in Firebug and in the Chrome Dev Tools that it's not.

```
$.fn.tooltip = function(userOptions)
{
    var defaultOptions =    {
                                position: '',
                                follow: true
                            };

    var options = $.extend(defaultOptions, userOptions);

    $(this).mouseenter(function()
    {
        var title = $(this).data('title');

        build(title, options.position, options.follow);

        var top, left;

        var tooltip = $('#tooltip');

        if (tooltip.hasClass('top'))
        {
            top = $(this).offset().top - ($(this).height() * 2) - 10;
            left = $(this).offset().left;
        }

        else if (tooltip.hasClass('right'))
        {
            top = $(this).offset().top - ($(this).height() / 2);
            left = $(this).offset().left + tooltip.width(); 
        }

        else if (tooltip.hasClass('bottom'))
        {
            top = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 10;
            left = $(this).offset().left;
        }

        else if (tooltip.hasClass('left'))
        {
            top = $(this).offset().top - ($(this).height() / 2);
            left = $(this).offset().left - (tooltip.width() * 1.5);
        }

        tooltip.css('top', top).css('left', left).show();

    });

    $(this).mousemove(function(e)
    {
        if (options.position === "" || options.position === undefined || options.follow === true)
        {
            var title = $(this).data('title');

            build(title, options.position, options.follow);

            var top = e.pageY + 25;
            var left = e.pageX + 10;

            $('#tooltip').css('top', top).css('left', left).show();
        }
    });

    $(this).mouseout(function()
    {
        $('#tooltip').hide();
    });

    function build(title, position, follow)
    {
        if ($('#tooltip'))
        {
            console.log("The tooltiop should be on the page.");
            $('#tooltip-content > p').text = title;
        }

        else
        {
            console.log("Position is: " + position);

            var markup  = '<div id="tooltip" class=' + position + '">';
                markup += '<div id="tooltip-content">';
                markup += '<p>' + title + '</p>';
                markup += '<span id="tooltip-arrow"></span>';
                markup += '</div>';
                markup += '</div>';

            $('body').append(markup);
        }
    }
};
```

The original goal was to create the tooltip the first time the user moves over the element and then when the mouse moves away I wanted to hide the tooltip and move it out of the way until it's needed again. That's why I'm checking to see if it exists in the build function. I know I'm overlooking something, I just can't figure out what it is. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In build function change the check in the if like:

```
if ($('#tooltip').lenght) {
```

that will return false if #tooltip is not yet appended to body and true if it is. 
The $('#tooltip') will return always a jQuery object thus it will never be false but its length will be 0, thus false, if the tooltip element is not yet added to the body.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzografski/ybv68rtk/)

Regards.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it had to be something simple.